# How do I make my program beep in a loop?

Tags: c++

I need help with some code, what i want it to do is be able to make the computer 'beep' using the alert function ie: \a but I don't know how to implement it so that the user can choose how many times it beeps while using a switch statement, All help will genuinely be thanked.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    int y;

    cout << "Do you want to make your computer beep" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    if (x == 'y' || x == 'Y')
    {
     cout << "How many beeps do you want" << endl;
     switch (y)
     {
      // This is the part i'm stuck on!!!
     }
    }

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, have you ever heard about "loops"?

Comment: Yeah, But how would i implement it 
do

while (x != y) 
or something explin a lil more

Comment: @FuzionSki: What platform are u using? There is a Beep() function in Windows, which can be used.

Comment: Are you new to C++ or to programming? If it's just C++ could you provide some pseudocode?

Comment: @Fuzion: I just hope you'll never release that in the wild, I *hate* beeps!

Answer (score 5):

You probably shouldn't use the switch to do that otherwise you will have to write a case for every number that they could possibly select.  A for loop should be used here:

```
int n;
cout << "How many beeps? " << endl;
cin >> n;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << "\a";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using switch you will never finish writting your program, there are y infinite possibilities! (Well, in fact there are –2147483648 to 2147483647) Use a for loop instead:

```
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
     int x;
     int y;

     cout << "Do you want to make your computer beep" << endl;
     cin >> x;
     if (x == 'y' || x == 'Y')
     {
          cout << "How many beeps do you want" << endl;
          for(int i = 0; i < y; i++)
          {
                cout << "\a";
          }
     }

     cin.ignore();
     cin.get();
     return 0;

 }
```

The "for" loop uses i as a counter and it's incremented 1 unit for each iteration, starting by 0, when i = y the loop ends, so you are doing from 0 to (y-1) beeps, counting the 0 beep the sum of all is y, and that is what you want :)